# after when searching the data appears, can't click on data and use asynchronous on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]

[image]

member_transac = 'member'

member = 'Selenium'

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, member_transac))).send_keys(member)
driver.find_element(By.ID, member_transac).send_keys(member, Keys.ENTER)

send_keys(member, Keys.Return) even with this script it doesn't work

is there a way to use a script that can execute commands in cases like this??